# Amazon SES: User is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail' on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've recently setup AWS SES and continue to run into the following error when sending email from a local application.

```
User `arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:user/mail_user' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:REDACTED:identity/mail@REDACTED.COM'
```

I've setup the below policy for the email mail@REDACTED.COM

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "SampleAuthorizationPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AuthorizeEmail",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:user/mail_user"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:REDACTED:identity/mail@REDACTED.COM"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions as to why I'm continuing to receive the unauthorized error?

Comment: The `Action`s are case sensitive and the right actions would be `ses:SendEmail` and `ses:SendRawEmail`. Examples at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-policies.html

Comment: @GSSwain I made the update but am receiving the same error. Do you have any other suggestions? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue I created an inline policy for the user via IAM (the permissions tab under the User).

I granted the following permissions to resource `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:REDACTED:identity/mail@REDACTED.COM`

- SendEmail
- SendRawEmail

I did not need to create an identity policy via the SES management panel.

Comment: I've learned in the general life that a perfect answer with no example still scores not much but its still a good eye opener

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using ElasticBeanstalk, but the problem was not on the smtp-user that SES required, but on the Role that Beanstalk created for the EC2 instance.

Solution was the same, tho. Make sure you select SES or SESv2 properly.